# How can we integrate resource file with any translation management tool

Tags: asp.net-mvc, localization, multilingual, globalization, resx

I am working on multilingual site developed in asp.net MVC. Currently we are managing the translation task using resource (resx) file and everything is working fine.
Now as per client requirement, they want to integrate our resource file to a TMS "phrase" through a webhook. So in future, if they create any new key or modifying the existing resource file. Its automatically reflects in application resx file and it should automatically reflects on dev/test/prod environment.

As I tried to update the resource file on API call, its get modified and changes are reflected on application.

But when we modified the resx file under app_GlobalResources folder then it restarts the whole application. so this is one of drawback to use this approach. Also when we deploy our changes then it makes the dll of app_globalreources. Post deployment, unable to add new or make changes in existing translation.

Can any one suggest a best approach, which we should consider to fulfill above requirement.

**Edit:-**
Can we use json instead of resx file in existing application.

Answer (score 0):

A common way to do translations is through database instead resource files. You save the same information in your database: language, key (the resource name) and value (the translated text).

With this focus, you must develop a way to do translations (the typical CRUD operations) and some layer to get any key in each language.

Talk with your client and check how important is this feature. I worked in a project like this some time ago and, at the end, we never do translations in this way. We add more functionality, made changes, translations and, when iteration finished, we move to production everything. Maybe not your case but it's a pity work on something that later hasn't use.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestion. As per their understanding, it will save the Dev team time to ask the translation. If any new translation get introduced then they will update the same on that tool and its get updated automatically. So they are asking to implement the same.

Comment: You can search for tools like https://github.com/HakanL/resxtranslator focused in non developers, to make the translations over the resource files

Comment: If we use database approach then there will be the chances of performance issue?

Comment: You always can load all resources at start (if you can have with resource files, it's no problem have all in memory) and use some focus to refresh (every X minutes, with a request...)